# Can I automatically append data to a link?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to access different data across browser windows.

For that I am planning to use sessionStorage.

E.g. for window1 I set: `sessionStorage.setItem('id','12345')`, for window2: `sessionStorage.setItem('id','67890')`.

To be able to process this, I want to send the info as a url parameter, so it would look like `/foo?id=12345`. Now, the `?id=12345` part should be appended to every link I click. So if a button links to `/foo2` it should automatically make it `/foo2?id=12345`.

I can't do `document.getElementById` for everything that links somewhere.

Is this possible via javascript or somehow else?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Did it work, not-work, break...? Can you please share your [mcve] code in order that we can easily reproduce your problem to provide an answer that's useful to you and future visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update all links on the page add add the parameter.

```js
const id = '123456';
// You will want to target all anchors, I am using a class
// due to the stackoverflow snippets having other links
//const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.my-url');
links.forEach(function(el) {
   const url = new URL(el.getAttribute('href'));
   const params = url.searchParams;
   params.append('my_id', id);
   const newUrl = `${url.origin}?${params.toString()}`;
   el.setAttribute('href', newUrl);
});
```

```html
<a class="my-url" href="http://www.example.com">My Link 1</a>
<a class="my-url" href="http://www.example.com?other=abc">My Link 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. However I am also using a lot of buttons for links with an onclick event like: onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Index' ". Can I use this the same way?

Comment: You may need to refactor your onclick handlers to pass the href through a function that appends the parameter.

Comment: I decided on basically making every link button an a element, the css is the same so that wouldn't be an issue.
But since all my links have the format /abc/xyz instead of a full url, I get the error: Failed to construct 'URL'. Is there a way to rewrite the js to also be applicable to those kinds of paths? Or can I just read it out as a string somehow?

Comment: The URL() constuctor can accept 2 params. The second one is a "base url" in the event your paths are relative.

Comment: I know, but it would be great if it worked without it, since I'm switching between localhost and server pretty often.

Comment: You don't need to hardcode it, just use `document.location.origin`

Comment: Okay, hopefully the last issue. Now the href text doesn't get included, it only takes the base path and combines it with the id. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8amxgt9r/

Comment: My bad, use: ```const newUrl = `${url.origin}${url.pathname}?${params.toString()}`;```